# Corrupted store of react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am looking for any suggestion to debug this issue.

Normally when my reactjs app starts, it initialises the state to the following

[image]

The `CollectionData` class is basically a class that consists of many properties of type `immutable-js` map.

```
export class CollectionData extends Immutable.Record({ // eslint-disable-line new-cap
  idToFetching: new Immutable.Map(), // Map<Id, Bool>
  idToError: new Immutable.Map(), // Map<Id, Bool>
  idToEntity: new Immutable.Map(), // Map<Id, Entity>
...
```

However for reason, for a certain route, the state is initialised to this

[image]

I don't know how it is possible how the properties of `CollectionData` is changed to `Symbol(react.element)`

I would like to know what is the best way to debug `initRoutes`.

I am using these dependencies:

```
 "react": "^0.14.6",
"react-chartist": "^0.10.1",
"react-dom": "^0.14.6",
"react-intl": "2.0.0-rc-1",
"react-redux": "^4.4.5",
"react-router": "^1.0.3",
"redux": "^3.0.5",
"redux-router": "^1.0.0-beta7",
"redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
"reselect": "^2.0.1",
```

**EDIT:**

When I expand the properties `store` and `type: function Row(_ref2)`, I saw these attributes:

1) Store: `validated: false`

2) Row: `arguments: TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context. at Function.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:3:14) at Object.InjectedScript.callFunctionOn (<anonymous>:124:124)`

[image]

The store is basically messed up and cannot be inspected in the Redux Devtool (a chrome extension). I think it is related to this error

[image]

Comment: Huh? Based on your screenshot you have `idToEntity` expanded? Otherwise they look the same?

Comment: If you look closely, the type is `Map` in the first screen shot and `Object` in the second. I expanded the second to show it is not an immutable map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is because there was an exception thrown by one of my components during mounting (In this case, a class called 'Row'). Remove the exception  and the problem is gone.